# Laravel functions in pivot models?

Tags: laravel, function, design-patterns, model, relation

We've got two tables that are in a relation to each other.

**User** and **Booking**.

The pivot model **UserBooking** sits between them.

We have a function that checks if there is also a specific value in the current record of **UserBooking**.

Where should this function be? 
In the **user** model or in the **pivot** model?

If this function returns something from **UserBooking**, it should be nested there I guess. 
How would I call this function in Laravel?

Is this a common pattern in Laravel? Whats the best practice?

Comment: As I understood your question you wanted those users who don't have or have bookings?

Comment: Not really. 
I want to know if I can run specific functions from the pivot model when I'm running a query. Especially when the function is based on this relation.

User::with('booking')->pivot-> function from pivot model

Something like this

Comment: Not sure your expectations. if you want to query from pivot then you can use wherePivot function https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: If you want to extend pivot model then 
class UserBooking extends MorphPivot
{
   // some functions
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previous discuss If you want to extend the pivot model then

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;
class UserBooking extends MorphPivot
{
   // some functions
}
```

and in relationship

```
public function bookings()
{
   return $this->morphToMany(Booking::class, 'user_booking')->using(UserBooking::class)->withPivot(['booking', 'user', 'data']);
}
```

Note: I used it for pivot casting and I do not use it for any function. I think it will helpfull for you.